# Scrapy is closing my spider while a loop isn't finished

Tags: python, scrapy

I am running a very simple scrapy loop to query several times in a row `https://api.ipify.org/`

```
class IpSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "ip"
    n = 0
    use_proxy = True

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            "https://api.ipify.org/", 
            callback=self.parse_ip
        )
    

    def parse_ip(self, response):
        if self.n < 10:
            self.n += 1
            self.logger.info(self.n)
            self.logger.info(response.body)
            yield scrapy.Request(
                "https://api.ipify.org/", 
                callback=self.parse_ip
            )
```

I expect that It will log something like

```
1
ip
2
ip
3
...
```

but the log looks like :

```
2022-09-01 08:43:38 [ip] INFO: 1
2022-09-01 08:43:38 [ip] INFO: b'ip'
2022-09-01 08:43:38 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2022-09-01 08:43:38 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
```

Please note that I am using a middleware which routes my requests through a proxy. It looks like :

```
def process_request(self, request, spider):
    if spider.use_proxy:            
        request.meta['proxy'] = 'proxy_ip:proxy_port'
    return None
```

Why does the scraper interupts the for loop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualy this is a normal behavior from Scrapy which fitlers out duplicate requests.

In order to allow for duplicates the request should include `dont_filter=True`

```
yield scrapy.Request(
        "https://api.ipify.org/", 
        callback=self.parse_ip,
        dont_filter=True
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you miss used the `yield` command in `parser_ip` method. This one will work only if some iterating loop call it. In your code you only call `parse_ip` once! you need to build a `for` loop.

Comment: No I am calling it several times. Once from the start_request and then in the if self.n < 10 loop